# Jquery UI autocomplete. How to write the results inside a div using innerHTML?

Tags: jquery-ui, html, autocomplete, innerhtml

I have an autocomplete field into my website. I just want to display the results inside a -div- tag instead the popup window that the plugin opens natively.

I searched already for solutions for this in other posts, but what they do is to change the position of the "popup" window, and what I want is to replace the content of the -div- with the results, not to put the popup over it.

Any advice will be very appreciated.

This is the code that I have:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

.

[image: Example]

Comment: @j08691 Here it is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BdZPX/5/

Comment: Please post some code *in your question*. Stack Overflow aims to be self-contained, and questions with a link to jsFiddle but no code are discouraged. Please read [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) for the rationale behind this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi OK, I made the changes. I didn't know about posting the code here, but it has a lot of sense. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As j08691 says, you have to handle the [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open) event of the widget. However, since you also want to select the items in the `#results` element, copying them will not be enough.

I would suggest you reparent the whole autocompletion menu under your `#results` element instead, and reset its [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) style attribute to `static` so it remains in place:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget")
               .appendTo("#results")
               .css("position", "static");
    }
});
```

You can see the results in [this update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdZPX/7/).

Comment: How can I replace the content of the div instead of adding the results at the end of it?

Answer (score 4):

Use autocomplete's open event like in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BdZPX/6/)**.

```
    open: function(e, ui) {
        var list = '';
        var results = $('ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget-content a');
        results.each(function() {
            list += $(this).html() + '<br />';
        });
        $('#results').html(list);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain the problem correctly. I want to display in the -div- the whole list of results that are selectable, and chose one of them in the -div-