# how to select value from drop down and click on it which is in div in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver

how to select value from drop down and click on it which is in div in javascript or jquery  ?Trying to enter value in the search box and select from  drop down and click on it,need to automate.
The value is in ul -> li -> div.

There is no select tag, input tag uses type='text' and role="combobox" and there is no href tag as well.

The code is in AngularJs

Comment: share your code instead...

Comment: [Read how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/image.html) ? Then you already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018669/jquery-ui-autocomplete-how-to-write-the-results-inside-a-div-using-innerhtml).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here a Library i developed

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".test").autoFill({
textField: "name",
valueField:"id",
datasource:[{name:'tst', id:"0", href:"https://www.google.se"}, {name:'tst10', id:"1", href:"https://www.microsoft.se"}],
onSelect: function(settings){
alert(settings.selectedItem.href);

}


})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/AlenToma/LightData.CMS/master/source/LightData.CMS/Content/Script/JqAutoFill.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/AlenToma/LightData.CMS/master/source/LightData.CMS/Content/Styles/JqAutoFill.css" />

<input type="text" class='test' value='None' />
```